# merge two pdf pages to one page itext

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to combine two or more pdf documents so that the pieces on each document appear on one page in a new pdf.

The pieces on each document contain a form with multiple fields, but the forms only take up a fraction of a page.  I know the typical way to merge documents in iText is PdfCopy.addDocument(reader), but I don't want each doucment on it's own page.

Is there a way to copy the fields and/or acroform of each document and put it into a new document where the snippets flow one right after another?

One way I have been thinking about doing this is creating a table with one column in a new document and adding each snippet into a cell, but I haven't been able to get it yet and I don't know if that is even possible.

Or is there a way to make the form a template and copy the template and put it into a cell in a table or on a new document?  I don't want the template for the entire page, just the form with the fields.

I also realize that PDF is page-based, but I was hoping there would be a way to combine two pdf pages with form fields onto one page.  Also, my fields do not need to be interactive.  The forms are already filled out and can be flattened if they need to be.

Comment: Something like this might work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3444936/231316

Comment: I tried that, but then the different templates overlay each other on the page.  Do you know of a dynamic way to move a template down a page so it comes after a previous template on the page?